# method to see if a linux kernel module is used and not just loaded (like aesni)

Tags: linux, kernel, aes

I'm looking for a way to see if a kernel module is really used, in my case aesni-intel.
I see that it's loaded in `lsmod|grep aes` and also used by other aes modules and crypto helper.

But i can't see if tools like `cryptsetup` or `libreswan` ipsec are using the module.

I see that the performance is better when loaded but sometimes that's not enough.

I also tried "`perf top`" and i see that `aes_enc_blk` is called but that's no ensurance either.

So **if anyone has any idea how to achieve this**, besides patching the linux kernel to log something when aesni-intel is called, i would appreciate it.

thanks